# Differentiation between typeof(int) and typeof(Int32) in C# possible?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types

got a simple question, and I think I know the answer but I wan't to hear it 
from some other people.

Let's say I'll create a generic function:

```
public string GetTypeName<T>()
{
}
```

It should return the name of the type T, which is easy:

```
return typeof(T).Name
```

*At this point we can ignore, that this does not work for generic types, that's not the subject of the question.*

**My problem is: If someone calls the function like that:**

```
GetTypeName<int>()
```

**It should return "int".**

**If someone calls the function like that:**

```
GetTypeName<Int32>()
```

**It should return "Int32".**

But I think thats not possible huh?

Thanks for answering!

Comment: There is no any difference. `int` is just C# alias for `Int32` type, and typeof always returns `Int32` and not `int`

Comment: As a side note, the described function in the first part of your question compiles just fine. https://dotnetfiddle.net/TzCXuq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The distinction is not possible, because the distinction does not exist.

`int` is a keyword which the compiler interprets to mean the `global::System.Int32` type as a shortcut or *syntactic sugar*. In other words, at runtime and within the .NET framework itself, there is no `int` type, only `Int32`.

The same applies to all the types which have keywords - see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx) for the complete list and their equivalents